# update multiple tables from one csv and get row id after update_or_insert

Tags: web2py

I'm trying to build a .csv data upload facility which will update two tables in sequence. So, i have my 'person' table which has a one to many relationship with the 'thing' table i.e. one person can own many different things.

What i need to do is get the primary key from a 'person' row after an 'update_or_insert ', this ID will then go into the 'owner_id' for the correseponding row in the  'thing' table.

Any ideas as to how i can do this? Excuse my programming i'm a beginner!

model

```
    db.define_table('person',
                        Field('name'),
                        Field('age'),
                        Field('country'),
                        format='%(name)s')

    db.define_table('thing',
                        Field('thing_name'),
                        Field('value'),
                        Field('location'),
                        Field('owner_id'))
```

controller

import csv

```
def importer():
    form = FORM(INPUT(_type='submit',_class="btn btn-primary"))
    if form.process().accepted:
        with open('C:/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/all_projects/web2py/applications/uploadTest/private/test.csv') as csvfile:
            readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            next(readCSV, None)
            for row in readCSV:
                name = row[0]
                age = row[1]
                country = row[2]
                thing_name = row[3]
                value = row[4]
                location = row[5]
                db.person.update_or_insert(name=name,age=age, country=country)
                db.thing.insert(thing_name=thing_name,value=value,location=location)
    return dict(form=form)
```

and the following data

```
person.name,person.age,person.country,thing.name,thing.value,thing.location
matt,38,uk,teddy,12,house
matt,38,uk,kite,13,outside
matt,38,uk,screen,14,shed
matt,38,uk,teddy,15,garden
will,24,us,table,16,house
will,24,us,teddy,17,outside
will,24,us,kite,18,shed
will,24,us,screen,19,garden
pete,56,bel,teddy,20,house
pete,56,bel,table,21,outside
pete,56,bel,teddy,22,shed
pete,56,bel,kite,23,garden
pete,56,bel,screen,24,house
pete,56,bel,teddy,25,outside
matt,38,aus,teddy,26,shed
matt,38,can,kite,27,garden
matt,38,fr,screen,23,shed
pete,25,bel,teddy,22,shed
pete,25,bel,screen,74,shed
```

ps - i'm getting the file locally as i havent worked out the .retrieve: method yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.update_or_insert` will not return the record ID in case of update, so you cannot use that method. Instead, simply check for and fetch the record to get its ID. For example:

```
        for row in readCSV:
            person = dict(zip(('name', 'age', 'country'), row[:3]))
            record = db.person(**person) # Check for a match.
            person_id = record.id if record else db.person.insert(**person)
            thing = dict(zip('thing_name', 'value', 'location'), row[3:6])
            db.thing.insert(owner_id=person_id, **thing)
```

Note, the `db.person(**person)` syntax returns the first record that matches all the values in the `person` dictionary (presumably you are expecting at most one match given your data) or `None` if there is no match (see the [documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Fetching-a-Row) for details).

Also, note that in case there is a matching `db.person` record, there is no need to update it, as all the fields you have available in the CSV file are already being used to find the match (i.e., there are no additional fields whose values need to be updated).

Comment: Thanks for that Anthony, that worked a treat! I'll post my final code once complete in case anyone needs it in the future!